# Create object and prevent from being destructed

Tags: c++, list, qt, class, constructor

I have a Class

```
class ListOfControllers
{
public:
    ListOfControllers();        
    ~ListOfControllers();    
    QList<RmgController> rmgControllers;

    QJsonObject toJson() const;
    void fromJson(QJsonObject obj);
};
```

In `fromJson` I want to read a json and fill the `QList<RmgController> rmgControllers`:

```
void ListOfControllers::fromJson(QJsonObject obj)
{
    .
    .
    .
            rmgControllers.clear();
            for (...)
            {
                RmgController rmg;
                rmg.fillWithValues();//fill the object with values from json
                rmgControllers.push_back(rmg);
                //at this point the DESTRUCTOR of RmgController is being called and the filled values CLEARED
            }
}
```

when I leave the scope of object creation the destructor of RmgController raises and clear all the filled values so the List (rmgControllers) contains some objects with default values not the values being read from json.

Comment: Perhaps you don't follow [the rules of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Hard to do more than guess without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your options depend on whether `RmgController` is move-aware(if you have given it custom copy operators and/or a custom deleter it's probably not). If not, you can use `emplace_back` (assuming QList has a similar interface to std::list).

Something like this:

```
    rmgControllers.clear();
    for (...)
    {
        // emplace default-constructed object at end of list
        rmgControllers.emplace_back();  

        // reference added controller
        RmgController&  rmg = rmgControllers.back(); 

        //fill the object with values from json
        rmg.fillWithValues();
    }
```

If `RmgController` is move-aware you can simply move it to the end of the list.

```
    rmgControllers.clear();
    for (...)
    {
        // create controller
        auto rmg = RmgController(); 

        //fill the object with values from json
        rmg.fillWithValues();

        // move new controller to end of list
        rmgControllers.push_back(std::move(rmg));  
    }
```

Comment: There is no `emplace_back()` and also the second solution did not worked and destructor called after the `push_back`

Comment: @mammadalius hmm that's a shame. You may want to consider using `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `push_back` to push a value into a vector, that value will be *copied* into it if the const l-value reference signature is selected.

To prevent that, you can construct the value in-place in the vector by using `emplace_back`, or by calling `std::move` to move the value when you push it back.

However, in your case it seems like the copy constructor of the class `RmgController` is not defined properly. If you have a pointer type member variable you have to define the customized copy constructor (plus copy assignment/ move assignment & constructor / destructor as well, this is called **Rule of five**), otherwise two instances of the same class might have pointers all point to the same shared resource/state, which leads to error.